# How to do one setUp for a unit test suite

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have the following to do two unit tests:

```
import unittest
from unittest import TestCase


class TestUM(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = SeleniumClient()

    def test_login(self):
        self.client.login()
        self.assertIn("my-data", self.client.driver.current_url)
        print ('Log in successful.')

    def test_logout(self):
        self.client.logout()
        print ('Log out successful.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

However, it does `setUp` twice -- once for each of the unit tests. Is there a way I can do one setup across all the unittests for `TestUM` ? If so, how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setupClass` for that:

```
class TestUM(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.client = SeleniumClient()
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUpClass), this method is called only once before tests in class are run.